# Making a reversed file without complications

Tags: file, python-3.x, reverse, os.path

I was attempting to take a file, reverse it, and save it to another file. However, I've come across a problem.

If I reverse this, for example:

```
The woods are lovely, dark and deep.
But I have promises to keep,
And miles to go before I sleep,
And miles to go before I sleep.
```

I should end up with this:

```
And miles to go before I sleep.
And miles to go before I sleep,
But I have promises to keep,
The woods are lovely, dark and deep.
```

However, what I end up getting is this:

```
And miles to go before I sleep.And miles to go before I sleep,
But I have promises to keep,
The woods are lovely, dark and deep.
```

This is my code, at the moment:

```
import os.path

endofprogram = False
try:
    fileName = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
    print("\n")    
    infile = open(fileName, 'r')

    outfileName = input("Enter the name of the output file: ")
    print("\n")
    while os.path.isfile(outfileName):
        outfileName = input("File Exists. Enter name again: ")
        print("\n")        
    outfile = open(outfileName, 'w')
except IOError:
    print("Error opening file - End of program")
    endofprogram = True

if endofprogram == False:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for reverse in lines[::-1]:
        print(reverse)
        outfile.write(reverse)

outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the last line of your input file doesn't end in a newline. There's a number of ways to deal with that; here's one:

```
for reverse in lines[::-1]:
    if reverse[-1] != "\n":
        reverse += "\n"
    #etc
```